# How to set the number of map tasks in hadoop 0.20?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to set the number of map tasks to run in hadoop 0.20 environment.

I am using the old api.

Here are the options I've tried so far:

```
    conf.set("mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum", "5");
    conf.set("mapred.map.tasks", "10");
    conf.set("mapred.map.tasksperslot", "5");
    conf.set("mapred.tasktracker.map", "5");
    conf.set("mapred.map.parallel.copies", "5");
```

With all of those on, the number of map tasks running parallely remains 2.

What are the proper options to set to get the number of parallely running mappers up to 5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [TaskTracker.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskTracker.java)

> maxCurrentMapTasks = conf.getInt("mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum", 2);

According to the ["Hadoop : The Definitive Guide"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do). So, setting the property on the client side is of no use. You need to set the same in the configuration file.

> Be aware that some properties have no effect when set in the client configuration. For
>   example, if in your job submission you set mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum with
>   the expectation that it would change the number of task slots for the tasktrackers running your job, then you would be disappointed, since this property only is only honored
>   if set in the tasktracker’s mapred-site.html file. In general, you can tell the component
>   where a property should be set by its name, so the fact that mapred.task.tracker.map.tasks.maximum starts with mapred.tasktracker gives you a clue that it can
>   be set only for the tasktracker daemon. This is not a hard and fast rule, however, so in
>   some cases you may need to resort to trial and error, or even reading the source.

Comment: would you be able to provide a proper configuration script for EMR?

Comment: what do you mean by a configuration script for EMR? Need more details.

Comment: when starting Elastic Mapreduce job, there is a possibility to run Bootstrap Actions before hadoop starts. I believe that this can be used to set the number of mappers, but I leak the know how

Answer (score 0):

***To keep answer up-to-date with changes in Hadoop API, I have listed new replacements for deprecated properties.***

```
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum => mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum
mapred.map.tasks => mapreduce.job.maps
```

Have a look at this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html) for deprecated API  & new API

But I prefer to keep number of map tasks decision to framework itself for better performance of job.