# Hadoop: number of available map slots based on cluster size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

Reading the syslog generated by Hadoop, I can see lines similar to this one..

```
2013-05-06 16:32:45,118 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient (main): Setting default number of map tasks based on cluster size to : 84
```

Does anyone know how this value is computed?
And how can I get this value in my program?

Comment: Which Hadoop version are you using? Do you use Amazon Elastic MapReduce on AWS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Amazon Elastic MapReduce on AWS. Hadoop version 1.0.4

Answer (score 3):

I grepped the source code of Hadoop and did not find the string `Setting default number of map tasks based on cluster size to` at all (whereas I find other strings, which are being printed when running MR jobs). Furthermore this string is not being printed anywhere in my local installation. A google search for it listed problems on AWS with EMR.
As you confirmed, your're in fact using Amazon Elastic MapReduce. I believe EMR has some own modifications to the [JobClient](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.java) class of Hadoop, which outputs this particular line.

As far as computing this number is concerned I would suspect it to be computed based on characteristics like `total number of (active) nodes in cluster (N)` and `number of map slots per node (M)`, i.e. `N*M`. However, additional AWS-specific resource (memory) constraints may also be taken into account. You'd have to ask in EMR-related forums for the exact formula.

Additionaly, the `JobClient` exposes a set of information about the cluster. Using the method [JobClient#getClusterStatus()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#getClusterStatus%28%29) you can access information like:

- Size of the cluster.
- Name of the trackers.
- Number of blacklisted/active trackers.
- Task capacity of the cluster.
- The number of currently running map & reduce tasks.

via the [ClusterStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ClusterStatus.html) class object, so you can try and compute the desired number in your program manually.

Comment: This seems to be useful but `JobClient` belong to the old package `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` and I'm trying to figure out how to obtain a `JobClient` from a `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` object.
I found also the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker` class which has the method `getClusterMetrics()`. It returns the information I need.. but again didn't find a way to obtain an instance of this object.

Comment: I think you're stuck with using `JobClient` here. Alternatively you could try access the JobTracker via JMX. However I'm not sure, whether it will provide all needed metrics. Retrieving gets much easier in hadoop 2.0. Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/pi/DistSum.java) shipped with hadoop's source code (lines 391, 405). It uses Cluster#getClusterStatus() to obtain a `ClusterMetrics` instance. `Cluster` instances are constructed via URLs like `JobClient`.

Answer (score 0):

So this is set by default based on the size of your input.  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces. You are allowed to specify more mappers, but not less than the number defined by hadoop.

You should be able to access this number by getting the configuration option "mapred.map.tasks". You can also get it from this function if you are using the old api.

```
conf.getNumMapTasks();
```

This previous question, [How to set the number of map tasks in hadoop 0.20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477700/how-to-set-the-number-of-map-tasks-in-hadoop-0-20),  has some good answers as well

Answer (score 0):

It is primarily the `InputFormat`'s duty to find the no. of mappers and it is done based on the `InputSplits` created by the logic written inside `getSplits(JobContext context)` method of your InputFormat class. Specifying the no. of mappers through the Job or config files or specifying it through the shell is just a hint to the framework and doesn't guarantee that you'll always get only the specified no. of mappers.

Comment: I don't think the question is about no. of mappers a job needs. The question is about number of simultaneous mappers a cluster can handle.