# hadoop multinode cluster - slave nodes failed to perform mapreduce task

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, cluster-computing

I am new to hadoop. I try to setup hadoop(version 1.2.1) cluster(1 master and 5 slave nodes) by following the post by Michael Noll at
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Before I am running the word count job on the cluster, everything seems good. When I start the cluster by running the following cmd on master node:

```
hadoop/start-all.sh
```

The jps output is correct:

On master:

```
li@master:~$ jps
12839 TaskTracker
11814 NameNode
12535 JobTracker
25131 Jps
12118 DataNode
12421 SecondaryNameNode
```

On 5 slave nodes:

```
li@slave1:~/hadoop/logs$ jps
4605 TaskTracker
19407 Jps
4388 DataNode
```

When I run stop cmd on master:

```
hadoop/stop-all.sh
```

jps gives nothing on master and slave nodes

But when I run the word count job on the cluster I think the cluster does not work alright. The task logs on slaves node did not match what Michael Noll got in his post. It seems the job only got executed on master. The other 5 slave nodes did not get assigned map reduce task to perform. Here are some log files:

console output on Master:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount /user/li/gutenberg /user/li/gutenberg-output
14/03/06 17:11:09 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
14/03/06 17:11:09 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/03/06 17:11:09 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/03/06 17:11:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201402211607_0014
14/03/06 17:11:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/03/06 17:11:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
14/03/06 17:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 57% reduce 0%
14/03/06 17:11:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 85% reduce 0%
14/03/06 17:11:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/03/06 17:11:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
14/03/06 17:11:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201402211607_0014
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 30
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=38126
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=2
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=7
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=5
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=9825
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=1412505
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=4462568
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=6950792
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=7810309
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=1412505
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=6950001
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=2915072
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=137146
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=2915072
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=507858
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=11435849
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1195069440
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=16520
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=1174991
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=791
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=201010
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=128513
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=201010
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=1252454400
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=128513
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=4080599040
14/03/06 17:11:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=1174991
```

tasktracker log on slave1:

```
li@slave1:~/hadoop/logs$ cat hadoop-li-tasktracker-slave1.log
2014-03-06 17:11:46,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2014-03-06 17:11:46,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2014-03-06 17:11:46,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0 which needs 1 slots
2014-03-06 17:11:46,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0 which needs 1 slots
2014-03-06 17:11:46,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0 which needs 1 slots
2014-03-06 17:11:46,336 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 1 and trying to launch attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0 which needs 1 slots
2014-03-06 17:11:46,394 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer: Initializing user li on this TT.
2014-03-06 17:11:46,544 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-862426792
2014-03-06 17:11:46,544 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-862426792 spawned.
2014-03-06 17:11:46,545 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-696634639
2014-03-06 17:11:46,547 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-696634639 spawned.
2014-03-06 17:11:46,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Writing commands to /home/li/hdfstmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/li/jobcache/job_201402211607_0014/attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0/taskjvm.sh
2014-03-06 17:11:46,551 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Writing commands to /home/li/hdfstmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/li/jobcache/job_201402211607_0014/attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0/taskjvm.sh
2014-03-06 17:11:48,382 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-862426792 given task: attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0
2014-03-06 17:11:48,383 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-696634639 given task: attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0
2014-03-06 17:11:51,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0 1.0% 
2014-03-06 17:11:51,459 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0 is done.
2014-03-06 17:11:51,460 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0  was 217654
2014-03-06 17:11:51,460 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 1
2014-03-06 17:11:51,470 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0 1.0% 
2014-03-06 17:11:51,472 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0 is done.
2014-03-06 17:11:51,472 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0  was 267026
2014-03-06 17:11:51,473 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
2014-03-06 17:11:51,628 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-696634639 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2014-03-06 17:11:51,631 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201402211607_0014_m_-862426792 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2014-03-06 17:11:56,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 192.168.1.111:50060, dest: 192.168.1.116:47652, bytes: 267026, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID: attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0, duration: 47537998
2014-03-06 17:11:56,076 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 192.168.1.111:50060, dest: 192.168.1.116:47652, bytes: 217654, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID: attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000004_0, duration: 15832312
2014-03-06 17:12:02,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received 'KillJobAction' for job: job_201402211607_0014
2014-03-06 17:12:02,320 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201402211607_0014 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1394233922320
```

tasktracker logs on slave2:

```
2014-03-06 17:12:06,293 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received 'KillJobAction' for job: job_201402211607_0014
2014-03-06 17:12:06,293 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown job job_201402211607_0014 being deleted.
```

slave4 and slave6 have the same task logs as slave1. slave3 has the same task logs as slave2 which has only 2 lines.

My questions:

```
1. Why the 5 slave nodes did not get task assigned?
2. Why slave2,3 have different task logs from slave1,4,6 when I set the same configuration on them
3. Is this a multinode configuration problem? How can I solve it?
```

Comment: Try giving bigger sized file(in GB's) for wordcount..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your task nodes have 2 map slots each:

`2014-03-06 17:11:46,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201402211607_0014_m_000003_0 which needs 1 slots`

The JobTracker is aware of this, and decided to assign as many tasks as possible onto a single node, instead of spreading them across as many nodes as possible.  This is probably done for reasons of locality (to minimize network traffic).

1. So that was why you had two idle nodes, because 5 tasks can be distributed to only three nodes with two slots (ceiling(5/2.0 = 3)).
2. Your logs will be different based on what tasks are running on a particular node.  So logs are expected to quickly diverge as you're running jobs on your cluster and they don't get evenly distributed among individual nodes.
3. This unequal distribution is not an indication of any problem; this is normal behavior for your cluster.  Remember that Hadoop is generally designed for batch work, meaning the normal case is that the cluster is heavily utilized with many jobs running, such that you won't get idle nodes even if your particular job is not running on all nodes.

Last note: in this particular case, it seems you're getting different
    behavior from the tutorial you followed, because you may be running
    on AWS (using Elastic MapReduce).  Apparently EMR has a custom scheduler
    that makes these mapping decisions (how many slots to allocate per
    node, and how to assign tasks over them) on its own without you
    being able to configure it.  More details in this answer:
    [Hadoop: number of available map slots based on cluster size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403576/hadoop-number-of-available-map-slots-based-on-cluster-size)
    .